# How do I find out which package owns a file?

Tags: debian, package-management, dpkg, aptitude

How do I find out what Debian package a file came from?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

To do this without installing any extra packages, run

```
user@host:~$ dpkg-query -S /bin/bash 
bash: /bin/bash
```

where bash is the package name.

---

Alternatively, there are several utilites in Debian which perform this task; check [this page](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/findfile.htm) for a description. I'll mention two of them, `apt-file` and `dlocate`.

`apt-file` searches its internal cache, thus allowing you to not install all the packages you want to search. Below you will find more detailed guide.

`dlocate` is a fast alternative to `dpkg -L` (the command that lists package contents), and as so, it searches only installed packages. Search is performed by `dlocate -S file.name`.

Also you can search packages online using [packages.debian.org](http://packages.debian.org) server (the **Search the contents of packages** section).

---

#### Installing and using `apt-file`

It's a good idea to update first:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

See what `apt-file` is for:

```
apt-cache show apt-file
```

Install it:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
```

Read data from repositories (this works also without `sudo` but creates user's cache then; with `sudo` the cache is system-wide):

```
sudo apt-file update
```

Perform search. In this example we want to know in which package `xrandr` executable is:

```
apt-file search xrandr
```

It lists many packages with `unxrandr`, `lxrandr.mo` or `source_lxrandr.py`. Not very useful in our case. More clever search:

```
apt-file search -x /xrandr$
```

(`$` denotes end of line). Example output:

```
bash-completion: /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/xrandr
x11-xserver-utils: /usr/bin/xrandr
```

The first result doesn't look like executable, the second one does. We can investigate further. Run:

```
apt-cache show x11-xserver-utils
```

Bingo! This is the package.

Comment: The first link in this answer (http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/findfile.htm) seems to be defunct now.

Comment: I have edited this answer and added the method using "dpkg-query -S" from https://superuser.com/a/179354/62940

Answer (score 152):

```
user@host:~$ dpkg-query -S /bin/bash 
bash: /bin/bash
```

Where bash is the package name.

Comment: This answer is far better than the accepted one!

Comment: Correct. It's unfortunate that the "accepted answer" gets a green checkmark, which is a mark that also conveys "correct answer". In this case, the accepted answer misses on `dpkg-query -S` AND it sends you down the wrong path of installing optional packages..

Comment: I've updated the accepted answer to include this "dpkg-query -S" approach

Answer (score 48):

Another alternative:

```
$ dpkg -S /bin/bash
bash: /bin/bash
```

On my Ubuntu at least, both seem to be in the `dpkg` package, so no real advantage to any specific one...

Answer (score 20):

**Installation generated files** will not be found by `dpkg -S`, as mentioned at: https://askubuntu.com/a/667227/52975

For example, `/bin/nc` appears when you install the package `netcat-openbsd`.

But upon:

```
dpkg -S /bin/nc
```

we get `dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /bin/nc`.

This happens because `/bin/nc` is generated by the `update-alternatives` call in the [postinst script](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/netcat-openbsd/trusty/view/head:/debian/netcat-openbsd.postinst) that gets run after installation.

It works like this because another version of `/bin/nc` is provided by the `netcat-traditional` package.

I don't think there is a general way of finding such generated files. In the specific case of alternative symlinks, we can just follow the link with `readlink -f`:

```
dpkg -S "$(readlink -f /bin/nc)"
```

Answer (score 6):

Not being familiar with Debian, I was baffled when I tried this:

```
kearnsp@xubuntuvb:~$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/vncviewer
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/bin/vncviewer
kearnsp@xubuntuvb:~$
```

A bit of investigation and I found the package:

```
kearnsp@xubuntuvb:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/vncviewer
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 May 28 15:49 /usr/bin/vncviewer -> /etc/alternatives/vncviewer
kearnsp@xubuntuvb:~$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/vncviewer
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 May 28 15:49 /etc/alternatives/vncviewer -> /usr/bin/xvnc4viewer
kearnsp@xubuntuvb:~$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/xvnc4viewer
xvnc4viewer: /usr/bin/xvnc4viewer
kearnsp@xubuntuvb:~$
```