# How do I find out which package owns a file?

Tags: debian, aptitude, package-management, dpkg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>    [How do I find out which package owns a file?](https://superuser.com/questions/179353/how-do-i-find-out-which-package-owns-a-file)

How do I find out what Debian package a file came from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
user@host:~$ dpkg-query -S /bin/bash 
bash: /bin/bash
```

Where bash is the package name.

Answer (score 8):

`dpkg -S /path/to/file`

Comment: I think you need the dpkg to be dpkg-query.

Comment: I don't think so...

Comment: Both work and both seem to be in the `dpkg` package...