# How to know which package owns a file in SUSE?

Tags: package-management, suse

A previous question, [How do I find out which package owns a file?](https://superuser.com/q/179353/364367) asked about Debian-based package management.  I have the same question for SUSE Enterprise 10, using YaST (or any other tool suitable for the task).

I'm looking for something similar to `apt-file` or `yum whatprovides`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for rpm based distributions:

```
rpm -qf /path/to/file
```

returns package `name-version-release.arch` string

for example:

```
mimi@argusek ~  $ rpm -qf /usr/bin/aclocal
automake-1.15-4.6.noarch
```

and in SUSE based distributions:

```
zypper search -f string
```

while string is searched part of the filelist in package

Comment: `zypper search -f string` does not work until package containing the file is installed. And that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me this works:

Code:

```
# zypper se --file-list gl3.h
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S  | Name                 | Summary                                | Type
---+----------------------+----------------------------------------+--------
i+ | Mesa-libGLESv3-devel | Файлы разработки для API OpenGL ES 3.x | package
```

However all of the above does not work if package containing the file is not installed:

```
# zypper se --file-list --match-substrings gl3.h
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
No matching items found.
```

So if file not listed in `provides` section then no way to find it until package installed.