# How to install and use xrandr in Debian?

Tags: debian, resolution, xrandr

Everywhere I look they say to use `xrandr` to change the resolution but when I try to use the command it is not found. I tried `apt-get install xrandr` (and `randr`) but the package could still not be found.

What is `xrandr`? Why can't I find it? How do I change my screen resolution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### About `xrandr`

From `man xrandr`:

> Xrandr is used to set the size, orientation and/or reflection of the outputs for a screen. It can also set the screen size.

In my `Debian GNU/Linux 7` I have found `xrandr` in the package named `x11-xserver-utils`.

Note `xrandr` is a tool to work with X server. It will be useless if you boot your OS with text console only and you want to keep it this way.

To install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install x11-xserver-utils
```

---

#### How to know which package to install?

Check [this question and its answers](https://superuser.com/q/179353/432690). In one of the answers I have created a basic guide to `apt-file` with `xrandr` as an example.

---

#### How to use `xrandr` to change resolution?

First simply invoke:

```
xrandr
```

You will probably see (among other things) some common video resolutions available to you, e.g.:

```
1360x768       59.8     60.0
1152x864       60.0
1024x768       60.0
```

You can switch to one of them like this:

```
xrandr -s 1024x768
```

Adding custom resolution is also possible. Read [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/377937).

Comment: Hmm I'm not using a GUI so perhaps that explains the issue.. So if i can't use xrandr, what can I do to fix my resolution? I'm using my tv as a monitor and only the middle of the command window is showing up

Comment: @CSCoder [See this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314406/108618). Don't forget to `update-grub`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't have time to give it a try till now but the  /etc/grub/ directory doesn't exist.. I'm trying to do this on C.H.I.P. so it might be a stripped down version of debian

Comment: @CSCoder I think you should mention this in your question in the first place. I don't know how Debian on C.H.I.P boots. There should be a way to pass `video=…` to the kernel. Or maybe there is `fbset` available – you could use [my old fix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314403/108618) then.