# Debian 11 can't find packages

Tags: linux, debian, apt

I recently installed Debian 11 and started messing around to the point where I can't find any packages with `apt`.
For example, when I run `sudo apt install ifconfig` it returns: `E: Unable to locate package ifconfig`.
I've read on a Dozen of pages that it would probably have to do something with my `sources.list` file.

I checked the file and everything seems fine to me.
Contents of `sources.list`:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main contrib non-f>
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main contrib n>

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free

#buster-backports
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free

deb http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
```

Does anyone have a clue on what could possibly fix this?

---

The output of `LC_ALL=C sudo apt update` is:

```
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease
Ign:5 http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

The output of `LC_ALL=C apt search ifconfig` is:

```
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
gnome-nettool/oldstable 3.8.1-3 amd64
  network information tool for GNOME

inetutils-tools/oldstable 2:2.0-1+deb11u1 amd64
  base networking utilities (experimental package)

iproute2/oldstable,now 5.10.0-4 amd64 [installed]
  networking and traffic control tools

libnet-ifconfig-wrapper-perl/oldstable 0.26-1 all
  multiplatform Perl wrapper for ifconfig

libnet-interface-perl/oldstable 1.016-1+b5 amd64
  Perl module for manipulating host network interfaces

libsys-hostip-perl/oldstable 2.120-1 all
  Perl module to determine local machine's IP address

moreutils/oldstable 0.65-1 amd64
  additional Unix utilities

net-tools/oldstable 1.60+git20181103.0eebece-1 amd64
  NET-3 networking toolkit

python-sh/oldoldstable 1.11-1 all
  Python subprocess interface

python3-sh/oldstable 1.14.1-1 all
  Python 3 subprocess interface

wmifinfo/oldstable 0.11-1 amd64
  Dockapp that shows information for all interfaces
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I just noticed iam reallly stupid. It indeed is not a package and when installing net-tools it does work...

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Consider accepting my answer then. ([See what "accepting" means](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/355310).)

Answer (score 1):

Your `sources.list` looks fine*, `apt update` works, `apt search` works.

The reason `sudo apt install ifconfig` returns `E: Unable to locate package ifconfig` is there is no package named `ifconfig`.

Please read [*How do I find out which package owns a file?*](https://superuser.com/q/179353/432690) An executable named `ifconfig` [is in a package named `net-tools`](https://packages.debian.org/search?lang=en&suite=bullseye&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=ifconfig). This should work and give you `ifconfig`:

```
sudo apt install net-tools
```

Note `apt search ifconfig` did find this package among few others. Your claim that you "can't find any packages with `apt`" seems unjustified.

---

<sup>* Except these `non-f>` and `n>` which I assume are results of posting what `nano sources.list` (or another text editor) prints when it truncates lines, instead of posting the actual *full* content of `sources.list`.</sup>